# WPF how to bind slider's value to label's content with StringConverter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a simple **slider** and a plain **label**. Label's content is bound to slider's value and it works fine- when you move the slider , label's content changes e.g 23.3983928394 , 50.234234234 and so on

**I'd like to round it to int values. 1,2,10....100** . But when I try to use a converter I get the  *"ivalueconverter does not support converting from a string".*

How can I convert the slider's Value to an int in the converter?

Thank you

This is my `XAML`

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <local:MyConvertor x:Key="stringconverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
<Slider x:Name="mySlider" Height="50" Width="276" Maximum="100"/>
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value, Converter=stringconverter}" />
```

This is my `stringconverter` class

```
public class MyConvertor: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //How to convert string to int?
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question: the error is thrown because of

```
Converter=stringconverter
```

it has to be

```
Converter={StaticResource stringconverter}
```

In your converter you convert not string to int but **double** (`Slider.Value`) **to object** (`Label.Content`) which can be a string too. e.g.

```
return ((double)value).ToString("0");
```

or

```
return Math.Round((double)value);
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the label. keyboardP's answer was very informative too but didn't work for the label...

Comment: Could you please briefly explain why using StaticResource works but if we omit it , it doesnt, as Im curious?

Comment: To make it clear:  the error comes from the XAML processor not from your MyConvertor. If you omit `{StaticResource ...}` the XAML processor tries to assign *stringconverter* as a string to the Binding.Converter which of course will fail because string doesn't implement IValueConverter. With `{StaticResource ...}` the XAML processor is looking for a resource named *stringconverter* and will find your converter in Grid.Resources.

Answer (score 21):

You could just use the [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property here instead of creating a converter. The double value will be rounded to an int due to the `#` format specified.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:#}}"/>
```

If you want to keep the label, instead of using a TextBlock, you can use [ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) instead as `Content` takes in an `object` type.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:#}" />
```

Comment: thx, If i change it to textbox then StringFormat works, but for label, the ContentStringFormat did nothing. it still shows a double value :(

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it I just tested it and it works fine for me. Are you sure you've typed it in correctly? Notice that `ContentStringFormat` is separate from the `Content` binding, unlike `StringFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use  the Label's ContentStringFormat property

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=Slider, Path=Value}" 
   ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N0}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the Slider's IsSnapToTickEnabled property